# Exporting/Saving a Python List to Variable Cell Range in Existing .xlsm Specific Sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have two lists I have created using a Python program, and I need to export those lists (each vary in length each run) to a specific sheet on a pre-existing excel macro enabled workbook. It will also be run and re-run, so "empty" can't be the overwriting criteria. The path will also change, as different people will be using it. I've tried pandas, and every excel interface python offers me, and can't figure out how to edit an existing book. Any help? Thanks!